# How to integrate $e^{t-u}du$

Tags: integration

I'm not quite sure how to integrate

$$\int e^{t-u}\,du$$

What particular rule do I use here?

Thanks

Comment: You have $$e^{t - u} = e^t e^{-u}.$$ Treat $e^t$ as a constant.

Comment: Ah I see, I knew it was something trivial, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can note that, since $e^t$ is a effectively a constant, the variable of integration being $u$, we have

$$\int e^{t - u} \,du = e^t \int e^{-u}\,du = e^t (-e^{-u}) = -e^{t - u}. \tag{1}$$

The *particular rules* used are:  i.)  $\int (cf(u))\,du = c\int f(u)\,du$; and ii.)  $\int e^{au}\,du = a^{-1}e^{au}$ for $a \ne 0$.  There may be others.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 2):

Change variable: $t-u=r$, $du=-dr$, from which you have
$$
\int e^{t-u}\,du=-\int e^r\,dr=-e^r+C=-e^{t-u}+C\;.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int e^{t-u}\,du = e^t \int e^{-u}\,du = \cdots
$$